# Dynamic component tag in tsx

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, tsx

How can I use a dynamic component name inside a tsx render function? This is what I'm after (not transpiling but just so you get the idea):

```html
<script lang="tsx">
    export default defineComponent({
        props: {
            hLevel: {type: String as PropType<'1'|'2'|'3'>,required: false,default: '3'}
        },
        setup(props) {
            const tag=computed(() => `h${props.hLevel}`)
            return () => {
                <div>
                    { <[tag.value]>title</[tag.value]> }
          </div>
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works fine with a static string, e.g.

```
const HeadTag = 'h1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your component and use it directly without `[]` :

```js
  return () => (
                <div>
                   <tag.value>title</tag.value>
          </div>)
```

Comment: I tried that too, it works if I don't add any attributes to the dynamic tag. But if I for example add `<tag.value role="tab">` I get "Type '{ role: string;' is not assignable to type 'ReservedProps'.
  Property 'role' does not exist on type 'ReservedProps'"